# logged_in user outside of wordpress loop

Tags: users, outside-wordpress

I have a member site which maintains a collection of books.  I want to have a page on a folder outside of my loop that can see if the user is logged in to the main site, and then display the book viewer.  If the user is not logged in to the main site, display a different page.  I think I am having some trouble with cookies.  I installed the [Root Cookie Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/root-cookie/download/), to help

This is the code I've put together, what needs to be done better:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
if (file_exists('../books/wp-blog-header.php')) {
    require_once('../books/wp-blog-header.php');
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: blog header does not exist';
}
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
// Start Site
$sitetitle = 'Book Viewer';
include 'head.php';

if ($current_user->ID == 0)
{
    include ('guest.php');
    exit;
}
else
{
    include ('viewer.php');
}
include 'foot.php';
?>
```

Should I be using `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header`  or do I need to do something with [wp_signon](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

Comment: Not sure what all the included files do here and where exactly is the problem.

Comment: @Chittaranjan Problem is that if I log in to my books website and then visit this page, it does not show that I'm logged in.  I'm guessing the cookies do not carry from wp site to an external page and need to write some sort of cookie check, but I do not know where to start or what the best way would be..

Comment: Can you check with `is_user_logged_in()` function?

Comment: @Chittaranjan I've tried both `is_user_logged_in()` and `current_user_can()`

Answer (score 0):

this worked with root cookie:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
if (file_exists('../books/wp-blog-header.php')) {
    require_once('../books/wp-blog-header.php');
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: blog header does not exist';
}

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

# Either load WordPress : http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website
# or Manually define your url like...

$cookieurl = "mybooksite.com";

define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( $cookieurl ) );

$cookiename = "wordpress_logged_in_" . COOKIEHASH;

$sitetitle = 'Book Viewer';
include 'head.php';


if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookiename])) {
    include ('viewer.php');
} else {
    include ('guest.php');
}

include 'foot.php';

?>
```

Not sure if there is a better/safer way to do this.